# Physical look to supersymmetry

Tags: symmetry, supersymmetry, fermions, bosons

A [supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) is a symmetry that transforms fermions into bosons and bosons into fermions. What's the physical interpretation of it? I could notice a symmetry between the boson sector and fermion sector, since if we exchange then into each other the theory we hold is the same. Is this interpretation correct and is there another, more rigorous, look to this symmetry in the point of view of theoretical physics?

Comment: Another way to think about it is that a supersymmetry generator is like a square root of a translation generator

Comment: What do you mean by "look"?